# hadoop streaming with anaconda(python) not working

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, hadoop-streaming

I am running a python script with hadoop streaming.
I have both python 2.7 and anaconda installed.

When I run the hadoop stream with python script using 
**#!/usr/bin/env python**
It works fine.

But when I use anaconda

```
#!/opt/anaconda/python2.7/bin/env python
```

It doesnt work.
 The MR job fails with below exception.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/hdfs1/yarn/nm/usercache/appcache/application_1430001030776_13989/container_e48_14776_1301_000/./mymapper.py": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
```

Does this means that I cannot use hadoop streaming with anaconda?

Comment: Why is your shebang line `#!/opt/anaconda/python2.7/bin/env python`? Shouldn't it be `#!/opt/anaconda/bin/python`?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you don't have `#!/opt/anaconda/python2.7/bin/env python` installed on each dataNode.

When you use `hadoop-streaming` only the file `mymapper.py` is sent to the mappers, not `python` interpreter.

You can fix this by installing `anaconda` on each machine from your cluster at `/opt/anaconda/python2.7/bin/env`.
As you can see using the default `python` interpreter works because it is  available on each machine from your cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try that and let you know if it works.